# How to disable logging to syslog from Node-RED

Tags: node-red, syslog

By default Node-RED duplicate to the syslog every message which has sent to console. Could anyone know how to disable that duplication? I need just put messages to consolw, not in syslog. Unfortunately there is no one word about syslog management inside logging documentation: https://nodered.org/docs/user-guide/runtime/logging

My settings.js:

```
// Configure the logging output
logging: {
    console: {
        level: "warn",
        metrics: false,
        audit: false
    }
},
```

Node-RED starts like this:

```
node /usr/src/node-red/node_modules/node-red/red.js --userDir /data flows.json >> /data/node-red.log 2>&1
```

Because i'm redirecting console to the log file. It is more convenient to me because I use Node-RED with Kubernetes cluster

Comment: We need more information about exactly how you are starting Node-RED

Answer (score 1):

Node-RED should only be logging to stdout/stderr by default, nothing should end up in the syslog.

The `node-red-start` script does redirect the logs to syslog (because it starts Node-RED with system) and then tails the syslog with `journalctl` so it looks like the output is being duplicated. But this should not be the case if you are starting Node-RED directly with node from the command line.

Comment: Thank you for the information. I'll check latest official Node-RED docker container to investigate.